# Gulp automatically watch for changes in scss file without running gulp watch everytime

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am new to this site and gulp.

I have 2 files - **sass/styles.scss** which compiles to **main/styles.css**

The problem is that it doesn't watch for changes like it is supposed to do automatically. It is supposed to compile the scss to css when ever I save it.

Right now, I have to to run **gulp watch** every time I make a change which is stressfull.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
return gulp.src('css/sass/styles.scss')
  .pipe(sass()) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
  .pipe(gulp.dest('css/main'))
  });

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('images', 'sass'), function(){
gulp.watch('images/**', ['oimages']);
gulp.watch('css/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']); 
});
```

**Terminal**

```
[19:37:02] Starting 'watch'...
[19:37:02] Starting 'images'...
[19:37:04] gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images
[19:37:04] Finished 'images' after 2.49 s
[19:37:04] Starting 'sass'...
[19:37:04] Finished 'sass' after 20 ms
[19:37:04] Finished 'watch' after 2.52 s
```

I want to make this an automatic process instead of running **gulp watch** every time I make a change to the sass file.

Answer (score 1):

Your function with the watch instructions should be inside `gulp.series`:

```js
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('images', 'sass', function() {
    gulp.watch('images/**', gulp.series('images'));
    gulp.watch('css/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
  })
);
```

Since the `'images'` and `'sass'` tasks are probably independent of each other, you could do

```js
gulp.series(gulp.parallel('images', 'sass'), function() {...})
```

or explore the [`ignoreInitial`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/watching-files#initial-execution) option.

Comment: Tried this but still not working. Stll have to run gulp watch each time I make a change.

Comment: Notice that I made two changes: 1) `gulp.series('images', 'sass'), function () {}` => `gulp.series('images', 'sass', function () {} )` 2) `gulp.watch('images/**', ['images'])` => `gulp.watch('images/**', gulp.series('images'));`